# Adding records to sorted sheet with multiple rows of the same name

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm implementing an app script that automatically inserts a new record to a spreadsheet containing multiple records. Currently, the target sheet is formatted as follows - with each record/name referring to several different data points:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Record Name | data 1 | data 1 |
|  | data 2 | data 2 |
| Record Name | data 1 | data 1 |
|  | data 2 | data 2 |
|  | data 3 | data 3 |
|  | data 4 | data 4 |
| Record Name | data 1 | data 1 |
| Record Name | data 1 | data 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Ultimately each new data point should be added under it's related record name if it exists or create a new record name otherwise. What I'm struggling to figure out is how to sort column A while maintaining the order of columns B and C relative to A since the number of data points isn't consistent and the record name is only in the same row as the first data point.

---

Things I've tried:

- Counting the number of empty cells under each record name and moving the data as necessary. The biggest issue here is performance since this method requires multiple loops through the data.
- Presorting the data (by hand, unfortunately). This works, but isn't very robust as multiple users can edit the sheet directly and makes adding new records more difficult.

I'm relatively new to Apps Script, so I feel like there's some library or function I'm missing. (It's also difficult to search for this problem, so I apologize if this is a duplicate)

Comment: Add expected output table for the given input and code that you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a pivot table based on your current table. You will need to fill Column A with data first. It has built in function for sorting your data. Unfortunately i don't think that it can expand its range dynamically. So you either have to give it a bigger range from the get go, or you can right a script that will delete old pivot table and create a new one after you finished adding new records into your table.
Here is a function that creates pivot table:

```
function createPivotTable() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getSpreadSheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();//Sheet with your source data
  var pivotRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,(sheet.getLastRow()-1),3);
  var pivotSheet = ss.insertSheet("Pivot Sheet");//Sheet with your formated data
  const pivotTable = pivotSheet.getRange("A1").createPivotTable(pivotRange);
  pivotTable.addRowGroup(1).showTotals(false);
  pivotTable.addRowGroup(2).showTotals(false);
  pivotTable.addRowGroup(3).showTotals(false);
}
```

If you want to create one manually you click Insert => Pivot Table and then choose which columns you want